# Get and Put extra, DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-dialogfragment

I'm writing an app where the user describes a problem and then receives advice. The user presses a button which shows a dialog with an `EditText`. Once the user presses `OK`, I want to get their input, but I'm having trouble with the extras. I've read similar questions, but I can't seem to find the problem. On a summary screen where I display the information, no text ever appears. Any help is appreciated!

I think the problem is when  I call `getText()` on the `EditText`. Using `log.d` the `mText` is just an empty String.

Here is my code:

The fragment `AdviceFragment` from which the dialog is called:

```
private static final String DIALOG_TEXT = "text";
private static final int REQUEST_TEXT = 0;
private Advice mAdvice;
private boolean hasText;

...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...

    mTextButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.textButton);
    mTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            InputTextFragment dialog = new InputTextFragment();
            dialog.setTargetFragment(AdviceFragment.this, REQUEST_TEXT);
            dialog.show(fm, DIALOG_TEXT);
        }
    });
}

...

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (resultCode == REQUEST_TEXT)
    {
        String text = data.getStringExtra(InputTextFragment.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (text.length() > 0)
        {
            mAdvice.setText(text);
            hasText = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mAdvice.setText(null);
            hasText = false;
        }
    }
```

`InputTextFragment` dialog:

```
public class InputTextFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "text";
    private String mText;

    private void sendResult(int resultCode)
    {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, mText.toString());

        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input_text, null);

        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        String input = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (input.length() > 0)
                        {
                            mText = input;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);               
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    ...
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: you started a dialogfragment not a activity so you dont see the results

Comment: Try creating an interface that the advicefragment will implement and declare it inside your dialogfragment and use it when the user press ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
```

You problem is here, your EditText is not added to your Dialog's View Tree. I think you should do like this:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(your_edittext_id);
```

> Thanks, I think this has fixed part of the problem. Using log.d in the
>   onClick() method of setPositiveButton()shows that it is successfully
>   assigning the value. However, I'm still not getting anything when I
>   call onActivityResult(). Do you have any idea what's going wrong?

Look here, another typo problem:

```
   if (resultCode == REQUEST_TEXT)
    {
```

It should be requestCode.

I think this should fix your problem, but you'd better follow bean_droid's suggest and use an interface instead of calling the onActivityResult() method. It's because that method may be called by other part of your code, which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, I think this has fixed part of the problem. Using `log.d` in the `onClick()` method of `setPositiveButton()`shows that it is successfully assigning the value. However, I'm still not getting anything when I call `onActivityResult()`. Do you have any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

```
    Public class AdviceFragment extends Fragment implements OkClickListener{

      @Override
      Public void onClick(String data){

       //DO YOUR CODE HERE
      }
}
```

InputTextFragment

```
 Public Class InputTextFragment extends DialogFragment{
       public interface OkClickListener{
             public void onClick(String data);
       }

 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input_text, null);

        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                    {
                        String input = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (input.length() > 0)
                        {
                            mText = input;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                       ((OkClicklistener)getTargetFragment()).onClick(data);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    ...
                })
                .create();
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. Google's official pages also suggest implementing interfaces.

Comment: onActivityResult wont work because your calling a dialogfragment thats why its not your not getting any data

Comment: In an Android book I'm using, one of their examples that was similar to my app used `onActivityResult()`, and they explained: "It may seem strange to call `Fragment.onActivityResult()` given that the hosting activity receives no call to `Activity.onActivityResult()` in this interaction. However, using `onActivityResult()` to pass data back from one fragment ot another not only works, but it offers some flexibility in how you present a dialog fragment."

I'm new to Android, so you may be right, but it did work in their example.

Comment: Well i never tried that one..  but this one works in me

Answer (score 0):

replace sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK); to getActivity().setResult(resultCode);